# SVN branch into trunk

Tags: assembly, svn, tortoisesvn, 68000

First of all, I have to say that I'm not too knowledgable on SVN's internal working, but it's been particularly difficult to, either find the proper info, or actually understanding whatever I got. So far, what I can say is that we all use latest TortoiseSVN version under Windows, and we like it for its easy merging feature.

Excuse me if I explain more than actually necessary, I don't know if I may or not dismiss any important detail here...
Years ago, our group released a Sonic the Hedgehog romhack on the Sega Genesis/MegaDrive, Mobius Evolution 1 v3.6. I still have a copy of that version's source code, but I can't release any "official" updates because its lead creator isn't reachable anymore.
After that first game, I got the task to be in charge of the Mobius2 sequel. At the same time, I had been working on improvements and bugfixes for Mobius1. Since I can't release v3.7 through "direct" means, I thought on the following: Assuming Mobius2 is CartA and Mobius1 is CartB, it could work like in S3&K, where you can stack CartB into CartA and "combine" the games. The player would link Mobius1 v3.6 into Mobius2, and Mobius1 v3.7 is playable.

This is the SVN structure:

```
trunk\<Mobius2>
branches\Mobius1\<Mobius1 v3.7>
branches\Mobius1Bkp\<Mobius1 v3.6>
```

Where we live our connections are slow, so we aim to keep commits as small as possible, minimal necessary. How Lock-On works (basic): When linked, ROM from CartB appears from address 0x00200000, which means although it's all readable, we can't run any of its code (anything that uses absolute addressing is bound to crash). CartA should therefore contain Mobius1 v3.7 program on itself too, but reading the music and art files from CartB (which is why v3.6 is still kept, so we still have the ROM addresses to said files).
During this time, as my friends work on Mobius2, I've been polishing the latest details so I begin porting v3.7 back. Program Init and a couple libraries would be different here though, and chances are I'll have to do further changes to Mobius1 repo afterwards too.

Is there any way, I could have ONLY PART of the latest Mobius1 branch, into Mobius2, make it optional (make anyone who isn't in mood could skip downloading it) have both to update... separately (?), and skipping unnecessary files too, such as the old build script or PrgInit?

or, Would you propose a different arrangement?

Thanks a lot!